# Sticky drag and drop QT bug found in Qt tree widget

Tags: qt

As such, the drag-and-drop feature will appear to our user to be quite broken.
This is a big issue that I am investigating now. I am convinced this is a Qt
bug. The question is what is the workaround?

All this is because of the following code segment:
setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection);.

Anyone aware of this? I will provide more information(how it is sticky) if its too hard to understand. I feel its a well known bug in QT

Comment: Please provide more information. It's hard to understand how it is sticky.

Answer (score 0):

There are some bugs with QTreeWidget, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283187/drag-and-drop-between-two-qtreewidgets).

But you got, at least, 3 ways to make it work:

1. Subclass QTreeWidget and reimplement drag and drop events.
2. Use Model/Views and reimplement drag and drop events. (And being similar to 1. is not the same)
3. event filters for drag and drop